# Can't get into the login screen/ stuck at boot after unmet dependencies

Tags: boot, dependencies

[image]

Hi all, I installed this specific version of libfreetype6 from a deb package, which unfortunately created this wide range of errors due to which I can't even logon to my Ubuntu as it got stuck at boot. In terminal through recovery mode, these are the dependencies error I got. I think due to these unmet dependencies I am having issues getting into my system. I would be very grateful for your suggestions as I desperately want my system back. Can't fix this with apt install - f and with other ways. The system got stuck with a small blinking line on boot, though I can get into command line mode, but with no help.

Comment: You cut out the important part of the error message, which command was not found (after "9 packages can be upgraded"). Have you tried to run the suggested command?

Comment: I did, but it fetched the same errors. Running sudo apt install -f fetched me same errors

Comment: The problem now is I can't even get into the login screen of my system, which should not have happened right.

Comment: Can you post the error you obtain at boot?

Comment: And again, which is the  command that was not found? You cut that out from your photo

Comment: More than an error, it just doesn't even reach the login screen and gives a straight blinking straight line, I may post an image, pls wait.

Comment: Can you run sudo apt-get purge libfreetype6 followed by sudo apt-get install libfreetype6?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/117386/discussion-between-roshan-shrestha-and-raffaem).